# WinSCP fails for one user

Tags: linux, winscp

We use **WinSCP** to transfer files from our developer's (Windows) boxes to Linux boxes in the lab. This works fine for all users, except this one, poor, unfortunate developer. He can connect to all other lab machines, except the one he needs to. Everyone else can connect to it.

He can get in with PuTTY (SSH), which is the same technology WinSCP uses. But when he tries to log in with WinSCP, he keeps getting a "Network error" message. We tried editing the `known_hosts` file, to no avail.

I know he's doing it correctly, because I've been right there over his shoulder, and even typed in the correct credentials myself. What else can we try?

Comment: There are any interesting logs on the ssh server?

Comment: The logs don't even show him trying to log in. They show him logging in via PuTTY. Double- and triple-checked login settings. They're all correct.

Comment: Sdow us WinSCP session log file and PuTTY event log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Network error" means just that: its not a problem with the server keys nor the credentials. Nor is it failing to negotiate a cipher (this causes the error "couldn't agree a client-to-server cipher") For some reason it is failing to resolve the name or complete a DNS handshake.

> the same technology WinSCP uses

erm no. Both are layered protocols (usually running on top of TCP) but the lower layers are the same. Normally they both use the same port number.

> (Windows) boxes

Presumably your employer hates its IT staff as much as mine.

From the networks point of view there is no difference between PuTTy and WinSCP. From the OS point of view, they are different programs. If they are behaving defferently then its because the OS is treating them differently. However if Applocker or your Anti-malware were responsible, then every winscp connection would be affected - not just that to this one target.

Have you checked there aren't problems with the name resolution? Before checking the hosts file and dredging through the registry for the search order, just try pinging the name and see if it resolves the correct address.

Have you checked that the same credentials work on a different machine? If different credentials work on this machine?

If so, then the next step would be to reinstall winscp. If that doesn't work, fire up wireshark and start diagnosing the network.

Comment: All good suggestions. He can ping and PuTTY into the machine just fine. Perfectly, even. The same credentials work from different machines, different credentials from his machine don't work, because, from the logs, it looks like WinSCP isn't even getting that far. I can look into re-installing WinSCP, but it may take a few days (company does not give us root access).

Comment: I just installed the "portable" version of WinSCP on the poor developer's machine, and that solved it. He had an older version of WinSCO (5.1.8). The latest version (5.11.1) throws up a certificate warning. The older version--I assume--just swallows the error and decides not to connect. So, since it was your suggestion, @symcben, I'm marking your response as the answer. Thank you!